# Qualcom atheros wirelless adapter not recognized in my acer v nitro laptop

Tags: wireless, drivers, acer, atheros

Please help me out I am novice in linux. I ran the command to check whether my wireless adapter is working. Below is the result.

```
deepu@deepu-Aspire-VN7-592G:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  ***-network UNCLAIMED**     
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   version: 32
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:84000000-841fffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 15
   serial: 30:65:ec:8d:42:d4
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.200.217 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:125 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:84204000-84204fff memory:84200000-84203ff
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with a temporary internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot. It will probably be missing the required firmware. Please find out and post:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

I will edit my answer to provide a method to locate and install the firmware.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Using this answer, I adjusted wireless connection, but is very slow and many packet loss. [Here](http://pastebin.com/A680YmMq) is my output of `dmesg | grep ath`.

Comment: @VeLKerr Please start your own new question.

Comment: no, I already solved my problem by creating config file: `echo 'options ath10k_core skip_otp=y' > /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf`.  The idea was taken from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1550790), see 10th message.