# Ubuntu does not recognize Killer wireless 1535 and ethernet e2400 in Alienware 2015

Tags: wireless, drivers, ethernet

I recently bought an Alienware 2015 which has a 1535 Killer wireless. When I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (Kernel 3.19) it did not recognize it. I did some search on the internet and found some methods to fix this issue on 1525 version of Killer wireless but I could not find any way to fix it for 1535.
I tried the method in http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/20-killer-wireless-ac-in-linux-ubuntu-debian but it did not work.
This is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` :

```
3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1535]
3d:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5227] (rev 01)
```

The output of `dmesg | grep ath10k` is nothing.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Comment: Please stick to 1 question at the time and describe what you have already tried. The way it is put now is more suitable for chat then Q&A.

Comment: Let's start with the wireless. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [patch](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/commit/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx?id=0208e951d55c435137543e12d7ee795c3784713a) on linux-next.git to get the ethernet going with source code from the 3.19 kernel

To get the ethernet going download https://www.dropbox.com/s/auk1g82st3yoy4d/alx.tar.gz?dl=0 and transfer it to the Ubuntu desktop.  Then in terminal

```
cd Desktop
tar zxvf alx.tar.gz
cd alx
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp alx.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/
sudo modprobe alx
echo alx | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

The wifi solution is likely https://askubuntu.com/a/707805/300665

After following the instructions from chili555, please edit your question to include `dmesg | grep ath10k`

Answer (score 0):

First try to get the firmware.

```
wget mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb

sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Reboot. This should fix your wireless adapter issues. If it does not, please post the output for `dmesg|grep ath10k` after following the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is kernel version `3.19` which didn't support your card at the time you were using Ubuntu 14.04 which is now EOL (End of Life).

On Ubuntu 16.04 and recent kernel `4.14.114` your commands now succeed:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

$ dmesg | grep ath10k
[    4.875579] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.876718] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    5.157111] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:3c:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    5.157117] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3c:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    5.157922] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[    5.157923] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    5.158332] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp crc32 fd869beb
[    5.222279] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
```

In contrast your `dmesg` command returned nothing.