# Wifi stops working every 1-2 hours

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.10, network-manager, atheros

My wifi will work fine for a while, but every 2 hours or so my connections drops. The wifi icon in the taskbar states that I am connected to the network, but I can't  access the internet. Rebooting fixes the issue, though when I reboot ubuntu gets stuck on a refreshing splash screen, unless I hold down the power key. This happens only once the wifi stops working, so they must be related. I tried `sudo service network-manager stop` and `sudo service network-manager start`, but then everything becomes really laggy and I have to hard reset anyway. I am using `Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter` on `Ubuntu 15.10`. If you suggest things to troubleshoot, I can wait for the next time it happens and post the output here.

EDIT: My question is not a duplicate of [Qualcom atheros wirelless adapter not recognized in my acer v nitro laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707746/qualcom-atheros-wirelless-adapter-not-recognized-in-my-acer-v-nitro-laptop) because my adapter is recognized just fine, my speed is find. My issue is that the connection drops every 2 hours and I have to hard reset the laptop to fix it.

However, running `dmesg | grep ath` as suggested there gives the following errors:

`[    7.048851] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2`

`[    7.049078] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-pci-168c:003e:11ad:0804.bin failed with error -2`

`[    7.049081] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qualcom atheros wirelless adapter not recognized in my acer v nitro laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/707746/qualcom-atheros-wirelless-adapter-not-recognized-in-my-acer-v-nitro-laptop)

Comment: Try to refer to this(http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and also try this script(https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) that will help you out in terms of debugging this issue

Comment: `dmesg | grep ath` gives me a long list of messages, among them is this error:

`[    7.048851] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    7.049078] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-pci-168c:003e:11ad:0804.bin failed with error -2
[    7.049081] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: failed to load spec board file, falling back to generic: -2`

Comment: The issue seems to have disappeared on its own.